# Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't boot at all

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I have a new Raspberry Pi 4 and it doesn't boot at all. I tried to decode blinking pattern by slowing down video record. And it looks like pattern is 2 - 2, which is "Failed to read from partition" (from official forum thread).
I tried 3 different sd cards, wrote with different hardware via official Raspberry Tool, or simply formatting it to FAT32 and copying NOOBS. Nothing seems to work

Comment: What power supply? What size sd card? I assume you used Pi Imager to flash Raspberry Pi OS? Is the Pi connected to a hdmi screen?

Comment: Yes, I tried different power supplies, from phone charge to monitor usb-c. I also connect pi to monitor via hdmi-0 port. I tried Pi imager with Raspbian and NOOBS

Comment: What specification of power supply, the official power supply is 5.1Volts 3.0Amps 18AWG cable? Do you see anything on screen when the Pi is powered on with no sd card?

Comment: I am trying huawei 5V 4A adapter. Screen doesn't react at all to me turning on pi.

Comment: What size sd cards? Might want to try using Etcher to flash as it verifies the card.

Comment: Well, the SD card is readable if it got to the 2-2 pattern - maybe try flashing and running the  *Raspberry Pi 4 EEPROM boot recovery* as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md)

Comment: yea, I tried flashing EEPROM, doesn't help :(